# Updating facebook android session permissions without logging out and in again

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I am using the Facebook SDK for an Android app which requires 2 permissions additional to the standard one for logging in/out.
The two permissions are a read permission: User Groups and a publish permissions: publish.

The problem is that in the latest facebook api requires to ask each permission separately. Which I am fine with.

The issue is that the session object is not updated with the new permissions after the user confirms them, unless I logout and login into the app again.

This would not be an issue if I could ask all permissions at once, but again, not possible anymore.

Is there any other way to avoid this?

And yes, I have tried everything in the **OnActivityResult**, and the permissions in the **Session.getActiveSession()** object is not updated with the new permissions, even though if I try to do the needed action it works.

And it's totally unfeasable to ask the user to logout and login of the app after each permission request.

This is what I have in my OnActivityResult (which works completely fine btw).

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("RADARE","ON ACTIVITY RESULT CALLED");
    Log.d("RADARE","REQUEST CODE: " + requestCode + " == RESULT CODE: " + resultCode + " == INTENT: " + data.toString());
    if (RESULT_CANCELED == resultCode) {
        Log.d("RADARE", "Canceled");
    }
   Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);



    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
        }
    });







     Session session = Session.getActiveSession();


     Log.d("RADARE","Session info: TOKEN: " + session.getAccessToken() + " == PERMISSIONS: " + session.getPermissions().toString() + " == STATE: " + session.getState());
     Toast.makeText(this, "You have to logout and login again in order for the service to work.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

My first idea would be instead of using Session.getPermissions().contains("needed_permission_here") to actually check online for the permission instead of the Session object.

Right now it just enters a loop:

The permissions are checked => permissions is not there => Jumps to facebook app asking for permissions => the user grants it => the app checks again for permission (which are not there even though the user has confirmed them) and jumps to facebook (which of course just replies back with the confirmed permission) and they dance back and forth infinitely.

Do you have any other ideas than checking the permissions online instead of the object?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from  [FB Login Permissions page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1)

user_groups- Limited Use

This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission

And for checking if the permissions are granted already

```
    private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions";

    <- Whatever read permissions you need ->
            authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday",
                    "read_stream", "user_friends","read_friendlists "));

    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {

                    if (session.isOpened()) {

                        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
                        if (!permissions.contains(PERMISSION)) {
                            pendingAnnounce = true;
                            requestPublishPermissions(session);
                            return;
                        }
}
```

I dont know how much  of help this will be to you..

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is not an issue. I have the permissions. And THAT is exactly how I am getting them right now.
The problem is that after the user grants the permissions, running this method again, in the Session object the permissions are not updated with the new and confirmed ones.

If I logout and login again in the app, the permissions are there and everything works fine.